# I need to add a options dropdown to a select element using an object of keyvalue pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what the object looks like:

```
0: {Key: "1", Value: "cat1"}
1: {Key: "2", Value: "cat2"}
2: {Key: "3", Value: "cat3"}
3: {Key: "4", Value: "cat4"}
4: {Key: "5", Value: "cat5"}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="edit-category-dropdown" class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-style="custom-select">
```

I need to add dropdown options to this select element with value attrib = object.key and the innertext to = object.Value.

I want it in this format ideally. 
`<option value=object.Key>object.Value</option>`

I have tried append to the element but it doesn't seem to work.

Update: apprently the issue was not my code that appended a new dropddown list but it was the fact that i didnt do a .selectpicker("refresh") on my select element. It fixed the issue with display.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I was able to get it working with my previous code. I just didn't realize it because it didn't display.However, the issue is with the bootstrap version of bootsrap-select. It doesn't seem to want to display my dropdown options. when i take the class="selectpicker" away from my attributes, it displays just a list of options which i don't want and prefer a dropdown list. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
$(availableOptions).each(function(_,item){
$('#edit-category-dropdown').append($('<option>', { value: item.Key, text: item.Value }));
$("#edit-category-dropdown").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```
I was able to figure it out. Seems like I just need to include .selectpicker to refresh it.
````

Answer (score 0):

Use some javascript:

```
var obj = [ {Key: "1", Value: "cat1"},
 {Key: "2", Value: "cat2"},
 {Key: "3", Value: "cat3"},
 {Key: "4", Value: "cat4"},
 {Key: "5", Value: "cat5"}]

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("edit-category-dropdown").innerHTML +=
"<option value='" + obj[i].Key + "'>" + obj[i].Value + "</option>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sweet and simple. I just write a basic `Javascript` `for` loop **method**. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
var array = [
 {Key: "1", Value: "cat1"},
 {Key: "2", Value: "cat2"},
 {Key: "3", Value: "cat3"},
 {Key: "4", Value: "cat4"},
 {Key: "5", Value: "cat5"}
]

var modelList = document.getElementById("edit-category-dropdown");
if (array) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var singleValue = new Option(array[i].Value, array[i].Key);
    modelList.options.add(singleValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="edit-category-dropdown" class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" data-style="custom-select">
```